# Azure Bot Service / Unable to Create Web App Bot / Location not supported

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have been trying to create a Web App Bot using the Microsoft Azure Portal. However, I have been unsuccessful in doing so, as I am constantly getting the error `"Location '{any server location}' is currently not supported"` when I try to add any new App Service-Plan. My active App Service Plan (B1, Linux, West Europe) is not even an option that I can select when choosing a plan.

I am somewhat confused and frustrated with this behavior as during my free trial period the creation of an Web App Bot did work and I am also able to create a Functions Bot.

I am sure, that there is some kind of problem with the App Service Plan, but I am not able to figure it out myself. Maybe one of you did stumble upon this issue already and is able to help me?

Comment: What is your current subscription? (you mentioned that previously was _free trial_). [Make sure that is valid first](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade). As a test; can you create an F1 AppServicePlan, outside of the bot creation dialog, then see if you can assign that in when creating a bot?

Comment: I am currently on a Pay-As-You-Go subscription. The subscription is valid and active. It seems as it took a day for all the Azure features to be available (I subscribed yesterday). I am now able to create Bot Services, assign and create AppService Plans. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I resolved it by changing "consumption plan" to "app service plan."

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPPuy.png)